# Black holes bending light

Tags: gravity, black-holes, photons, mass

Ok so I've been watching some videos about black holes but there is one thing I don't get: how can light be bent by black holes since photons don't have any mass?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Light_deflection_and_gravitational_time_delay

Comment: This question is too large in scope, you are basically asking people to  explain this whole thing to you. It would be more fruitful, if you try to read and understand it and then ask a specific question about which specific part you are stuck in or are not able to understand.

Comment: ok I'll do it on my own

Comment: Light travels on “straight lines in curved spacetime” called geodesics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Source of Light bending](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/390396/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34352/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you one quick answer that will help you to understand.  Gravity bends spacetime so that EVERYTHING falls, from apples to light itself.

You have probably heard that if you shoot a bullet horizontally and drop a bullet, they will both hit the ground at the same time.  So from this, you can understand that if you had a really really big, really really flat planet, if you shoot a bullet horizontally, drop a bullet, and shine a laser light horizontally, they will ALL hit the ground at the same time.

This will get you on your way for a question that is vast in scope and understanding.